# How to create a vector of objects stored by value?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a vector of immutable "Entry" objects.

```
#include <vector>

class Entry{
private:
    const double mLimit;
    const int mQty;

public:
    Entry(const double limit, const int qty) : mLimit(limit), mQty(qty) {}
};

int main(){
    std::vector<Entry> entries;
    entries.push_back(Entry(1.9, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

This the output of the compiler:

```
>>> g++ test.cpp && ./a.out 
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = Entry; _Alloc = std::allocator<Entry>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Entry*, std::vector<Entry> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = Entry*]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:925:17:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Entry; _Alloc = std::allocator<Entry>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Entry]’
test.cpp:15:36:   required from here
test.cpp:4:7: error: non-static const member ‘const double Entry::mLimit’, can’t use default assignment operator
 class Entry{
       ^
test.cpp:4:7: error: non-static const member ‘const int Entry::mQty’, can’t use default assignment operator
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:69:0,
                 from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc:343:16: note: synthesized method ‘Entry& Entry::operator=(const Entry&)’ first required here 
    *__position = __x_copy;
```

It seems like a simple mistake. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Remove `const` from fields

Comment: You are missing a copy constructor or move constructor. You could also do `entries.emplace_back(1.9, 3);`: https://ideone.com/fVwDe3

Comment: @mch Hi, I tried to add a copy constructor but I get the same error.

Comment: @mch     Entry(const Entry& other){
        mLimit = other.mLimit;
        mQty = other.mQty;
    }

Comment: `Entry(const Entry& other) : mLimit(other.mLimit), mQty(other.mQty) {}` is the correct copy contructor and it works with it: https://ideone.com/mBpdHE

Comment: @mch  Thanks for the help! I see that it works but when I compile it with g++ on ubuntu it still outputs the same compilation error.